# Unable to locate package Python

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to run the below Dockerfile contents on an [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) image.

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install flask
COPY app.py /opt/app.py
ENTRYPOINT FLASK_APP=/opt/app.py flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

But I'm getting the below error at layer 3.

```
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu
---> 549b9b86cb8d
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update
---> Using cache
---> 78d87d6d9188
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get install -y python
---> Running in a256128fde51
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python
```

although while I run the below command individually

`sudo apt-get install -y python`

It's successfully getting installed.

How can I fix this?

Note: I'm working behind an organization proxy.

Comment: try to build without cache `--no-cache`

Comment: Why do you need to build from ubuntu ? There is already a Python image for docker  https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Answer (score 2):

```
Step 2/7 : RUN apt-get update
    ---> Using cache
```

You should run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in the same RUN instruction as follows:

```
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python
```

Each instruction in a Dockerfile will create a separate layer in the image and the layers are cached. So the `apt-get update` might just use the cache and not even run. This has happened in your case as well. You can see the line `---> Using cache` in your logs. You can use `docker build --no-cache` to make Docker rebuild all the layers without using cache.

You can instead just use the `python:3` official image as the base image to run your Python applications.

Answer (score 2):

In the Python installation tutorial, there is a package name Python 3.x for [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).
I think this is your case. I tested it in the Docker and this is the right configuration.

It looks like

From *ubuntu:20.04*:

RUN `apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3.8 python3.8-dev`

Answer (score 1):

I feel you should rather use Python 3's image instead of using Ubuntu and then installing it.

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-pip # You don't need to install pip, because it is already there in python's image

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/apps # This you can change

WORKDIR /usr/src/apps/ # This as well

CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It worked for me.

```bash
apt-get install python3-pip
```

And then for installing [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29), you will have to use

```bash
pip3 install flask
```